Unsupervised Real-Time Pattern Counting in Time Signal Data Without Prior Knowledge
I'm facing a problem and it seems I can't find a working solution since a few years.
TLDR : Is there a well-known algorithm or NN-model that is able to autodetect and count patterns in a time signal without knowing anything a-priori on the pattern itself ?
My problem is : How to count, in real time, the number of patterns inside a time signal without knowing anything a-priori on the pattern itself.
What we don't known about the pattern is :

Its duration
Its minimum and maximum
Its frequencies
Where it will "pop out" (except at the beginning, refer below)
The "ambiant" noise

What I know about the pattern is :

At the beginining of the process I can rely on the fact that I will have N contiguous periodic patterns in the signal. N is a free parameter that we can force. In practice, it's not always possible to do so for big values of N
The pattern may vary a bit over the time around a "nominal state" randomly, let's say about 20% variations in terms of its periodicity, amplitudes and frequencies
After some time, the signal may or may not contain contiguous patterns
There can't be two or more different patterns. Only one

I will take 3 simple examples to illustrate this :

A snoring man that snores periodically for 2 minutes then may snore again randomly over its night
The number of bip sounds a machine is making
The number of heat cycles of a machine observing its temperature

About the system itself, there is not much to say as its defintion may evolve regarding the needs in terms of computational power (CPU/GPU + RAM). The only think to consider is the fact that I'm trying to build an automatic system that learns itself everything to know to count those patterns without knowing nothing about the signal/pattern itself a-priori. So no system expert is possible here as in the ECG field for example were the pattern is well described.
I've tried several methods so far making my system work under several hypothesis. Some methods work well for very short periods : About 100 ms to several seconds and others for periods above several seconds. Some use frequency domain other time domain but nothing enough generalistic (like the M-theory ? :D)
Each method can be splitted into two parts. A learning part that uses a batch of data and a counting part in real time. The learning part will "listen" the signal for a certain amount of time and compute some features. The counting part will exploit those learned features as the reference and recompute them in real time to see if there is a match. If so a pattern has been found and the counter is incremented by one.
Because the problem seemed hard to solve, a first idea was to get as an input an estimation of the pattern's duration. I'm not a huge fan of this and I'm trying hard to get rid of this hypothesis.
Just to give you some hints on what I've tried so far :

Several ideas based on 1D and 2D (on the spectrogram) correlations. Not resiliant to variations accross the time
Using an estimation of the period given as an input, I've labelised a learned pattern sliced into chuncks based on frequencies and amplitudes and done some distances computation on strings using Hamming/Levenstein to have a pattern matching
Statistics computation to build the features

Since a few weeks I'm trying to explore deep learning : RNN and CNN but building a neural network that handles my constraints seems impossible as the dataset itself will not have the same input size for example given the fact that the patterns size are not identical across the training patterns.
A new idea is to consider overfitting as the solution to my problem (a bit counterintuitive I know). It means training a CNN to do pattern matching on a specific dataset acquired in real time on a specific input signal but it means 3 things :

Generate a tiny dataset/ground truth on a few patterns : N patterns
Find a way to autodetect the pattern’s duration using growing autocorrelation windows for example but there is a strong needs for heavy computational power for patterns duration of more than a few minutes
Hope for the CNN to converge quickly using this tiny training dataset. Because in my understanding, training a NN means a lot of data

What do you think ? Do you have in mind well known methods or models that fit my needs ? I did'nt find relevant research papers on that matter as it seems an unknown problem or a problem known to have no solution.
Thanks for at least reading this until the end ;)
